# How to get content of a request in mocked service in SoapUI?

Tags: mocking, soapui

I want to get headers and content of POST request made to SoapUI Mock Service.

I've got it running and I can see it captures the requests because it returns responses and there's a log with date and mapping.

I've read that I should type in `OnRequest Script` tab `log.info mockRequest.requestContent` and restart the service.

That makes no difference and when I click green arrow a windows pops up with error: `NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'requestContent' on null object` so I believe the advice I found online is false or maybe there's another way of executing this.

Here's the window of the MockService and the error:

[image]

Comment: Are you using or need it in `Script Dispatcher`?

Comment: I have no idea. I just need to compare requests made in SoapUI client and my Java app and figure out why they are different :)

Comment: See documentation [here](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html)

Comment: Could you be more specific? I've already seen this doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I don't need to run the green arrow near script field.

Just type like in the question: `log.info mockRequest.requestContent` in `OnRequest Script` and the output is in the main SoapUI window.

Just click `script log` at the bottom:

[image]